# how to show youtube video thumbnails

Tags: php, youtube, thumbnails

my site lets users upload the youtube video codes. I am trying to make playlist by showing the thumbnails of the uploaded videos and play the respective video after clicking on specific thumbnail.

i would like to know the method of getting the caption and the thumbnail pictures of those videos which has been uploaded using embed code of youtube?

Edit:

To make question more clear, my users uploads code like one given below:

```
<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-L8DFfSJbqU&hl=en_US&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-L8DFfSJbqU&hl=en_US&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object>
```

so from those code how can i find the vedio id first then secondly the thumbnail picture?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thumbnails you can load from video url.

VIDEO URL

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xzf0rvQa4Mc

THUMBNAIL URL

> http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg
>
> http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg
>
> http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg
>
> http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Mc/default.jpg

It takes some time to replicate images to all thumbnails urls (maybe servers) for new videos.

If there is no thumbnail, it returns image with camera (exactly 893 bytes length).

EXAMPLE

> > http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/Xzf0rvQa4Md/default.jpg

Comment: better with this regexp (youtube\.com\/(watch\?v=)?(v\/)?([\w\-]+)) it can handle both urls (with /v/ and with watch?v=)


preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([\w\-]+)/', $code, $match); echo $match[3];

Comment: No problem. But study GData API for youtube. If you are able to parse video ID now, you can fetch more informations (title, ...).

Comment: Can these thumbnails be retrieved over https instead of http?

Answer (score 24):

You can try for different types of YouTube videos thumbnails by using these urls -

For the default & normal quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality (HQ) thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/hqdefault.jpg
```

There is also a medium quality thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/mqdefault.jpg
```

For the maximum resolution thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<youtube-video-id>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

For eg .

```
YouTube link - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8
YouTube video id - 4EvNxWhskf8
```

So that -

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/4EvNxWhskf8/hqdefault.jpg" title="YouTube Video" alt="YouTube Video" />
```

Comment: Perfect Thx alot :D

Answer (score 3):

With YouTube API:

```
   /* Some stuff goes before here to initialize API connection */

   /* Then get started: */
   $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube()
   $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('the0KZLEacs'); //Video-ID
   $videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails()

   echo 'Video: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoTitle() . "\n";
   echo 'Video ID: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoId() . "\n";
   echo 'Updated: ' . $videoEntry->getUpdated() . "\n";
   echo 'Description: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoDescription() . "\n";
   echo 'Category: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoCategory() . "\n";
   echo 'Tags: ' . implode(", ", $videoEntry->getVideoTags()) . "\n";
   echo 'Watch page: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl() . "\n";
   echo 'Flash Player Url: ' . $videoEntry->getFlashPlayerUrl() . "\n";
   echo 'Duration: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoDuration() . "\n";
   echo 'View count: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoViewCount() . "\n";
   echo 'Rating: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoRatingInfo() . "\n";
   echo 'Geo Location: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoGeoLocation() . "\n";
   echo 'Recorded on: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoRecorded() . "\n";
```

Can all be found here: [Developers Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html)

Comment: how to extract the "the0KZLEacs" video id for the api from my above code

Answer (score 2):

easily you can go to my website i created an application for this purpose,

http://shofnee.com/metal_shofnee/apps/youtube_app/youtube_app.php

also this is the code i wrote to get this application live with php language

```
 <?php
                //getting and validating the embed code
                $cde = $_POST['txt_embd'];
                if(!empty($cde))
                {
                $part_one_cde = explode("/",$cde);

                $part_2_cde = explode("?",$part_one_cde[4]);

                $img_1 = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$part_2_cde[0]/0.jpg";
                $img_2 = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$part_2_cde[0]/1.jpg";
                $img_3 = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$part_2_cde[0]/2.jpg";

                echo "Img 1";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<img src=\"$img_3\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />";
                echo"<br /><br />";
                echo "Img 2";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<img src=\"$img_2\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" />";
                echo"<br /><br />";
                echo "Img 3";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<img src=\"$img_1\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" />";

                }
                else
                {
                echo "Please put any embed code to get it's pics ...";  

                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your video id you could use links described in [this article](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-grab-and-download-the-you-tube-video-thumbnail/)

The link format is following:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/default.jpg
```

**Update**

If this is code you have:

```
<object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-L8DFfSJbqU&hl=en_US&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-L8DFfSJbqU&hl=en_US&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object>
```

then this is video link:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/-L8DFfSJbqU&hl=en_US&fs=1
```

then this is video id:

```
-L8DFfSJbqU
```

so your thumbnail link is:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/-L8DFfSJbqU/default.jpg
```

Comment: how to extract it using php? any suggestion

Comment: you can use regular expression, for example this is regular expression that can help you "http://www.youtube.com/v/(.{11})". You can get it using this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

The GData API for youtube allos you to fetch information about feeds, users, video etc.

This link describes the section of the reply relating to thumbnails:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_media:thumbnail

Do not hardcode URLs because Google can change them whenever they like. Use the APIs.

Comment: it was very useful about knowing the api... will be checking out it soon too