# How to Show Video thumbnails in UITableview?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiwebview, thumbnails

In my application i get the video link from Sever in UITableview .all these link are store in text file on server.But i want to get the thumbnails of these link in UITableview. here is my image .

[image]

As my Screen shot show the link which i fetch from server but NO thumbnails of these link show in red circle. These red circles are my webviews.here is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier ";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
} 
// Set up the cell.
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, [Listdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], cell.webSal.frame.size.width, cell.webSal.frame.size.height];    

cell.lblSal.text = [Listdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.webSal loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

return cell;
 }
```

When i use NSlog it show some thing like this.

[image]
Any one can Guide me that what mistake i make.Thanx in advance.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405059/how-to-show-youtube-video-thumbnails

Comment: Please nslog the value of html before [cell.webSal loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing on simulator. The thumbnails won't be displayed on simulator. You can see the video thumbnail when run in device.

Comment: @rakseshNS your idea is right.when i check it on device its work fine.Thanx for reply.

Comment: @ rakeshNS you are Right dear.thanx